# Gantt Chart online

Tags: javascript, python, charts, gantt-chart

I need to insert a horizontal bar chart in a web page. The thing I have to do is very similar to a Gantt Chart.

I'd like to use a javascript library for the purpose. I tried jsgantt, but actually it is not very beautiful.

I could evaluate also a server generation of the graph. In case my server side language is Python.

It will be part of an internal project with no internet access, so Google Charts isn't an option.

Answer (score 10):

Have a look at the [flot jQuery plugin](http://code.google.com/p/flot/):

> Flot is a pure Javascript plotting library for jQuery. It produces graphical plots of arbitrary datasets on-the-fly client-side.
>
> The focus is on simple usage (all settings are optional), attractive looks and interactive features like zooming and mouse tracking.

The library can produce bar graphs, and is used by our host site - have a look at Stack Overflow [Reputation History](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6491/gimel?tab=reputation&sort=graph) page.

Comment: example iin Stack Overflow is simple bar chart that shows events over time, not gantt.  Here is better example. http://www.jumware.com/Includes/jquery/Flot/Examples/Gantt.html

Comment: When the suggestion (flot) was made (nearly 4 years ago), flot was in use by the SO reputation graph. Today it uses http://www.highcharts.com/ , and will probably use something else 4 years from now.

Answer (score 7):

This is a complete jQuery based Gantt Editor Mit licensed

http://roberto.open-lab.com/2012/08/24/jquery-gantt-editor/

If you want a "complete" review of available ones see here:

http://roberto.open-lab.com/2012/06/14/the-javascript-gantt-odyssey/

I Have recently added SVG based drawing and collapse/expand tree functionality.

See http://roberto.open-lab.com/2014/05/15/jquery-gantt-editor-collapsible-branches/

Answer (score 4):

For me, the best is http://gantter.com/ you don't need registration process, it exports to msproject or pdf.... perfect!

Comment: This is awesome, I wish I saw it before. Thank you.

Comment: This is far from answer. It's online solution, you cannot implement it in your app.

Answer (score 4):

Try one of this:

http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGantt/index.shtml - neat chart, option to edit tasks, one serious drawback: lacks timescale change

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/gantt.html - free (!!), quite nice, but very hard to customize (unless you modify the source code)

http://bryntum.com/gantt/ - so far, one of my favourites - very easy to customize, but licensing for commercial projects is unclear, you can download trial for 45 days

http://www.tgantt.com/treegrid/www/Gantt.html - actually, this one looks like a space vessel's dashboard and so it is to configure, still struggling to put this in my application

Comment: http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGantt/index.shtml nice, but very expensive, 699$ for enterprise license

Comment: dhtmlxGantt 2.0 supports customizable time scale so you can change the time scale dynamically: http://www.dhtmlx.com/blog/?p=1993

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at http://www.ext-scheduler.com. 100% JavaScript, based on ExtJS. Disclaimer: I wrote it.

Comment: Licensing is unclear, looking for alternatives.

Comment: Define unclear? If you have any questions, feel free to contact me directly on Skype: mats.bryntse :)

Comment: I can't just use it like tgantt - pay and forget. The license is per server per users - how could I guess how many users will my customer have in one year time? The fee is annual and I need to buy extjs license separatelly. Sorry to say that, but tgantt, which is far more sophisticated, offers much better pricing and clearer licensing.

Comment: Well, if you change your mind you know where to find us :)

Answer (score 2):

[JQuery Gantt Chart](http://mbielanczuk.com/2011/06/jquery-gantt-chart/) - the best I tested

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that [**RadiantQ's jQuery Gantt Chart Package**](http://www.radiantq.com/) is missing in this discussion. This is relatively new, but has a lot of features, customizable and can be bound to any kind of data. The online demo is **[here](http://demos.radiantq.com/jQueryGanttDemo/Demo.htm)**.

Answer (score 1):

For Gantt chart generation see:

- http://www.mechanicalcat.net/tech/pytaskplan/
- http://www.strout.net/python/piddle/
- http://opensched.sourceforge.net/

or there are general charting libs like

- http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/
- http://home.gna.org/pychart/

or may be just use [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can get some impressions of how it could be done by these examples:

- http://www.yuml.me/
- http://creately.com/
- http://www.chartle.net/
- http://www.lovelycharts.com/
- http://www.icharts.net/
- https://scrumy.com/
- http://chartgizmo.com/
- http://www.archimy.com/
- http://www.gliffy.com/

I hope these are enough for some inspiration.

Comment: This answer could be improved making those URL's into links. As in [title](URL).

Answer (score 0):

see also [Open Flash Chart](http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart/index.php)
it gives support helpers also for the most popular programming languages.

Comment: open flash chart is nice but has no gantt chart inside

Comment: yes of course but is quite simple to make custom chart

Answer (score 0):

You could use FusionWidget at http://www.fusioncharts.com/widgets/gallery.asp. It's not free, but its Gantt chart works greatly for me.

Comment: Are you still using this Gantt Chart? I have troubles with it representing many horizontal processes...

Answer (score -1):

I like this one, is still under development, "use it at your own risk" but it's very drag and drop

http://ganttapp.appspot.com

Comment: just had a quick look, and it seems not very usable...

Comment: we're fixing the interface during this summer :p it's going slow lately due to cross projects :(

Comment: Currently 404, unavailable...