# difficulties in developing gantt chart using jquery plugins

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, gantt-chart

I'm trying to develop a gantt like chart using jquery plugins and asp.net mvc2...
on the y-axis i like to have names of people to whom tasks will be assigned...
while on the x-axis i like to have the tasks...
i haven't found good plugins for this...so any suggestions???
it is also important to have more than 1 task on a row, i.e. sam kan have more than 1 task on the same row...
i'm thankful for your help 
Lina

Comment: I think the answers to this question will help: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005587/gantt-chart-online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005587/gantt-chart-online)