# javascript gantt charts -charting data by day/hour/minutes

Tags: javascript, jquery, gantt-chart

I would like to use data from third party scheduling software to produce gantt or timeline type diagrams for displaying plant scheduling data on web page.  Requirements include

- javascript/html(5)/css solution (no flash if possible)
- primarily for gantts/timeline type charts, but other chart types may be useful
- based on jquery or prototype if possible
- time scale should allow for hours/minutes - this is important for scheduling labor/machinery.  (5 minute intervals might
  be sufficient)
- open source or low cost
- prefer not to have to roll my own solution

I can bring in data and manipulate it with PHP and javascript. I looked at a few packages  (most summarized here - [Gantt Chart online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005587/gantt-chart-online)), however most seemed weak on representing time in terms of hours and minutes.  jQuery.Gantt looked like the best solution, although it seems to suffer from lack of ability to display clearly intervals in minutes or fraction of hours.

Does anyone use package for these requirements, or able to overcome limitations of jquery.gantt?

thanks

example. In this jquery.gantt rendering, it is not possible to determine if work should commence at 16:10 or 16:15.
[image]

Comment: See this StackOverflow thread, has a few good options summarized. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9085614/gantt-chart-in-javascript-jquery-extjs

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [dhtmlxGantt](http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGantt/index.shtml), an open source (GPL) JavaScript Gantt chart. It has a customizable time scale so you can display hours/minutes scale, and supports easy integration with jQuery.

(Disclaimer: I work for DHTMLX)

Comment: i checked this URL. But Gantt chart is under licence only. pleas can u clear this one

Comment: dhtmlxGantt has GPL version as well, please check this https://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGantt/#editions-licenses

Comment: Because when reading GPL license detail, I still do not really comprehend, I want to ask here : Is it legal to use GPL version of the library for commercial project ?

Answer (score 4):

RadiantQ's [jQuery Gantt Package](http://radiantq.com/jquery-gantt-package-features/) is ideal for implementing your requirements. It's built using native HTML5, supports Hours, Minutes and custom time scale types are supported.

Filled with a huge set of features and customization options, you should be able to plot any information on a timeline.

You can easily bind to any JSON or other kinds of data and also use MVVM patterns like KO.

Take a look at that online demos [here](http://demos.radiantq.com/jQueryGanttDemo/Demo.htm).

Comment: looks very powerful.  My needs are more just for displaying existing data, not entire online application.  I am not sure if Radiant supports this. $700-1400 price tag is not quite free, but still much cheaper than developing our own.

Comment: Note that the package has 2 jQuery Gantt Widgets which can be configured to display your data. 

The above link is an online demo page that was created to illustrate the different features available in the gantt. You, will only integrate the widget into your pages and populate it with your data.

Answer (score 4):

Is anyone else still looking for such a Gantt chart library with granular timescales (Minutes-Seconds)?
I found Google Charts Gantt [Google TimeLine Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline) quite useful (although they call it TimeLine chart)

Another free to use Javascript chart library with gantt is [Amcharts](http://www.amcharts.com)

Answer (score 2):

I too started a project with [jQuery.Gantt](https://github.com/taitems/jQuery.Gantt). I ran into the same inconvenient, and later I found this one. Hopefully this will help other people:

[angular-gantt](https://www.angular-gantt.com/demo/)

I have not tried it on production or big data sets though. The benefits from this library is that it's MIT licensed which means you can use it in a commercial solution.